# Matlab lsqlin constrain N number of elements in solution

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, linear-programming, least-squares

I have a standard 
 `x = lsqlin(C,d,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)` problem. However, given I have a universe of approx. 700 rows in `C`, I find that the solution in `x` contains hundreds of very small values and a large `N` (number of elements).

If my solution should only possibly contain `N*`non-zero elements and with the vector `x` remaining the same length, is there a way to prevent small values? By specifying either a maximum number of non-zero `N`, or a minimum value *if* an element is chosen?
Vectors `lb=0` and `ub=1` apply.

Comment: This is sometimes called a cardinality constraint (max n nonzero) or semi-continuous (x is zero or greater than a lower bound). Unfortunately this brings you to the area of discrete optimization. No way to do this with lsqlin.

Comment: Ah. Thank you Erwin. I wonder if looping through and removing those below tolerance would achieve the same thing? Or do you think this would introduce path dependency?

Comment: That would be a heuristic. It will give you a good but not necessarily the best solution.